# @angular-devkit/core@13.3.5 requires a peer of chokidar@^3.5.2

Tags: angular, npm

Estoy intentando instalar Angular, pero me sale esto:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm install -g @angular/cli
C:\Program Files\nodejs\ng -> C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng.js

> @angular/cli@13.3.5 postinstall C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\@angular\cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

npm WARN @angular-devkit/core@13.3.5 requires a peer of chokidar@^3.5.2 but none was installed.

updated 1 package in 23.771s
```

Ya intenté con "npm install chokidar@3.5.2" y "npm install chokidar@^3.5.2 --legacy-peer-deps" pero me devuelve ésto:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.2 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN system32 No description
npm WARN system32 No repository field.
npm WARN system32 No license field.

updated 1 package in 1.063s
```

Realmente necesito instalar Angular y se me esta haciendo imposible..

Comment: Hasta ahí no hay ningún error.

Comment: y ese aviso de que requiero peers de "chokidar@^3.5.2" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para cada dependencia que muestre ese warning, se hace

```
npm install --save-dev xxxxx
```

Digamos, `npm install --save-dev chokidar@^3.5.2`. Así no saldrá más adelante. Los *otros warnings* claramente están advirtiendo de una dependencia OPCIONAL que no es compatible con windows. Fin.